# Смещение кнопок

Tags: android, android-sdk, android-fragment

Есть панель, на которой находятся 3 кнопки, после какого-то события вторая кнопка должна стать невидимой setVisibly(View.INVISIBLE), как сделать, чтобы после скрытия второй кнопки, 3 кнопка стала на место второй, т.е. произошел сдвиг? Если есть, то можно фрагмент кода

Comment: Я думаю в принципе можно менять само изображения в imagebutton

Answer (score 5):

Попробуй вместо View.INVISIBLE использовать View.GONE, он в отличие от INVISIBLE обнуляет размер невидимой вьюхи.